# MySQL select all the entries older than 10 days

Tags: php, mysql

Good day all, I'm developing a small script that has to check if an entry from a MySQL database is at least older than 10 days from now.
the table has a timestamp field (which is the one I would like to use, but I can change it if needed).
Actually I'm using this sql string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries 
WHERE tag='$tag' 
  AND DATE(last_update) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

but I'm discovering some selected entries "younger" than 10 days so maybe I'm mistaking something.
is this the right way or is better to check it via PHP (and not with the MySQL query) ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an example ? Like `CURDATE() = X` and `DATE(last_update)=Y` what would be an example of a bad Y being returned?

Comment: I cannot know this, because the last_update field is getting "updated" every times, the only clue I got of the wrong behaviour is that I have a "post count" field that is incremented every time, and I have found some of thise countes to be increased too much

Comment: It's usually helpful to test your queries in a DB shell. It wouldn't typically alter the data.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`older than 10 days` should be `before` the calculated date.

```
SELECT * FROM entries 
WHERE tag='$tag' AND DATE(last_update) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: ehm...you are right... I guess I messed up something.

Comment: Even if last_update is a dateTime you don't need Date()

Comment: Every time I google I wonder why it is so complicated. I mean in ideal world syntax should be like DATE>10d

Comment: @ArsenIbragimov, because it's a "Simple" Query Language. When they were making it, they wanted to create something that could be easily read by a human... and obviously failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use DATEDIFF():

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries 
WHERE tag='$tag' 
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(last_update)) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider your query and add a negative interval value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries 
WHERE tag='$tag' 
  AND DATE(last_update) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY)
```